# Facebook Dynamic ads for travel, pixel didn't load

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-pixel

I have to create Facebook Dynamic ads and Facebook pixel. I'm new in Facebook pixel. I read in https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2061728277446768?helpref=faq_content .
Facebook required many parameters for Search, AddToCart, Purchase event.
In Search page, I placed this code in tag head

```
 <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
    !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
            n.callMethod ?
            n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
        };
        if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0';
        n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
        t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    }(window, document, 'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '1338286652942310');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
```

And in body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//fbq('track', 'Search');

fbq('track', 'Search', {
content_type: ‘flight’, 
departing_departure_date:  Date0,
returning_departure_date: Date1,
origin_airport: Origination, 
destination_airport: Destination 
});

</script>
```

But Pixel Helper shows error
"The Facebook pixel code on this page didn't load, so no information was sent to Facebook."
[Pixel Helper error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmXvw.jpg)

I tried fix it. I checked Extensions but I didn't install AdBlock.

[my Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkSPW.jpg)

Please help me. 
(I'm an online marketer. I know a little about programming.  Sorry if my post isn't clear.)

Comment: Confused, why would it say the pixel code was `fbq('track', 'Search');` - I only find that line commented out in the source code of your page, `//fbq('track', 'Search');` Below that is an extended call with more parameters, but that doesn't seem to be what the Pixel Helper is seeing. Is this the only place where you are calling this, or could one of the external scripts maybe contain this too? Could you try and remove that commented line, maybe the pixel helper gets tripped up by that.

Comment: Thank you very much CBroe. But unfortunately it still shows error.